# How to delete the .xml and .log file when the premature uninstall is occurred in WIX

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I have created Wix installer for service and is working fine. The problem is when the service is not started for any reason For ex: (IP address given wrong, DB-script is wrong or Active MQ problem) during installation time, the roll back  is not completely clean the directory structure. Still it contains my explicitly contain .log file and .xml file.  But during uninstall it clear every file. The problem is how to delete .xml and .log file in premature uninstall.

```
<Fragment>
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
    <Directory Id="BallyTechnologies" Name="Bally Technologies">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="LfvGateway">

        <Directory Id="Logs" Name="LfvGatewayLogs">
          <Component Id="RemoveLogFiles" Guid="*" KeyPath="yes" Win64="no"
                     Location="either">
            <RemoveFile Id="LogFiles" On="uninstall" Name="*.log" />
            <CreateFolder />
          </Component>
        </Directory>

        <Directory Id="LfvGatewayServiceFolder" Name="LfvGatewayService">
          <Directory Id="ConfigurationFolder" Name="Configuration">
            <Component Id="RemoveXmlFiles" DiskId="1" Guid="*" KeyPath="no"
                       Location="either">
              <CreateFolder />
              <RemoveFile Id="XmlFiles" On="uninstall" Name="*.xml" />
            </Component>
          </Directory>

          <Directory Id="DBScriptsFolder" Name="DatabaseScripts">
            <Component Id="RemoveLogFilesDBScript" DiskId="1" Guid="*" 
                       KeyPath="no" Location="either">
              <CreateFolder />
              <RemoveFile Id="LogFilesDbScript" On="uninstall" Name="*.txt" />
            </Component>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>

      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory >
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use a **[rollback custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371369(v=vs.85).aspx)**. They are normally used to undo changes made by a custom action, but you should also be able to use it to delete temporary files added by your installation. You set this in the [Execute attribute of the CustomAction Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html). Thorough testing is needed to make sure there are no side effects.

[Here is an Installshield article on rollback custom actions](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpCustomActionRollback.htm). And [here is one more](http://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/setting-up-rollback-custom-actions/).

Comment: I created the custom action and apply for it, but it not execute   in the rollback. how to apply it. please make it correct  to me. I see the below link and apply for it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx